# Can Flow Designer set Audit Fields on insert?

Tags: flow, data, create-records

We are leveraging Process Builder and Flow to assist in a data migration. In the past we've only relied on Process Builder for data migrations and we've been able to define audit fields like `createdDate` and `createdById`. However, this migration is a bit more complex as we want to generate child record as well - therefore we are relying on Flow.

Does anyone know if Flow is capable of defining audit fields on record insert?

- Yes, we are creating the records as opposed to updating them
- Yes, we have the set audit field feature enabled
- Yes, field level security is set properly

Knowing Process Builder can support this function, I would assume Flow could as well. I'd rather not resort to it, but if needed we can rebuild this function in Process Builder.

---

Edit: What we are seeing is a `Record Create` flow element that does not have the CreatedDate field available for assignment. We search for the audit fields, but they are not available.

Comment: Our best guess is that due to Flow leveraging the Users login session to modify the records, it relies on a users ability to set audit fields on create - which not everyone has. Whereas Process Builder relies on APIs to perform the action making it available for a user to define audit fields.

Comment: As Flow and Process Builder use the same engine my gut feel would be yes, but it sounds like the audit fields are not available through the UI.

Comment: Ahh - that's an interesting thought. We will try to add the field anyway and see if it saves... doubt that would work either though.